# java.net.ConnectException while running webservice?

Tags: java, soa, oim

I am developing the web service where in I want to connect to the SOA server. It's giving connection exception.

Code:

```
public class ConnectSOA{

    public static void main(String[] args){

            Map<IWorkflowServiceClientConstants.CONNECTION_PROPERTY, String> connProperties = new HashMap<IWorkflowServiceClientConstants.CONNECTION_PROPERTY, String>();
            connProperties.put(IWorkflowServiceClientConstants.CONNECTION_PROPERTY.CLIENT_TYPE,WorkflowServiceClientFactory.REMOTE_CLIENT);
            connProperties.put(IWorkflowServiceClientConstants.CONNECTION_PROPERTY.EJB_PROVIDER_URL,"t3://10.10.78.79:8001");
            connProperties.put(IWorkflowServiceClientConstants.CONNECTION_PROPERTY.EJB_INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
            try {
                workflowServiceClient = WorkflowServiceClientFactory
                        .getWorkflowServiceClient(connProperties, null, null);
                itaskQueryService = workflowServiceClient.getTaskQueryService();
                statePredicate = new Predicate(
                        TableConstants.WFTASK_STATE_COLUMN, Predicate.OP_EQ,
                        IWorkflowConstants.TASK_STATE_ASSIGNED);
                iworkFlowContext = itaskQueryService.authenticate("demouser","demo1".toCharArray(), null);
            } catch(Exception e ){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Exception :

```
java.net.ConnectException: t3://10.10.78.79:8001 Bootstrap to: hostname/'10.10.78.79:8001' over: 't3' got an error or timed out
```

I have check the soa server its up and running on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

**[Can you ping your weblogic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/admin_ref/cli17.html)**?

```
java weblogic.Admin -url t3://IP:8001 -username xxx -password xxx PING 10
```

I see that you have 10.10.78.79:8001 and in Exception IP:8001

Could be that your server is not ok. Check the config. See your config.xml and what the listen address for the server is and verify that you can ping it.

Comment: Hey i had wrote that wrong i have edited question correctly. Ok

Comment: When i ping the weblogic with IP and hostanme it was replying the bytes.

Comment: Can you provide entire stacktrace? Do you run your code in your IDE or java command prompt? Can you run with debug/verbose enabled? Does your user exist (demouser / demo1) ? Tried enter a domain other than null (check your config properties). But most of all we need to see complete stacktrace!